# Error exporting geodataframe (with linestring geometry) to shapefile

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile, shapely

I'm using python in a Jupyter notebook to read data from multiple shapefiles into a geodataframe to process and combine the data, then attempting to export it back out in a single shapefile, but am experiencing issues with the export.

In an attempt to debug, I've tried narrowing the geodataframe down to only a couple of rows of data and important columns (ID, average speed, geometry), which looks like this:

| TT_Id | AvgSp1400 | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 48.28 | LINESTRING (150.8199199999999962 -34.5689100000000025, 150.8199999999999932 -34.5694799999999987) |
| 2 | 37.25 | LINESTRING (150.8201699999999903 -34.5705699999999965, 150.8202100000000030 -34.5705999999999989, 150.8202400000000125 -34.5706399999999974) |

When I run the following code to try to export the data:

```
output_shapefile_path = r'C:\Users\User.Name\Desktop\Folder\combined_data.shp'
test_gdf.to_file(output_shapefile_path)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'has_z'
```

Or sometimes:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'geom_type'
```

I've been able to visualise the full dataset without any problems using Kepler within my Jupyter notebook, so it seems that the error is more related to the export process rather than issues with the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your geometry column actually named "geomtry" or is that a typo just in your question?

Comment: Good pick up - that was just a typo in my question sorry. Fixed. As noted, I can read the geodataframe into Kepler and it works fine. I also tried checking type(test_gdf.geometry) and it returns "geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries". It's just when I try to output to Shapefile that I run into issues.

Comment: can't reproduce this using:

geoms = [shapely.wkt.loads(
    'LINESTRING (150.8199199999999962 -34.5689100000000025, 150.8199999999999932 -34.5694799999999987)'),
         shapely.wkt.loads(
             'LINESTRING (150.8201699999999903 -34.5705699999999965, 150.8202100000000030 -34.5705999999999989, 150.8202400000000125 -34.5706399999999974)')]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'TT_Id': [1, 2], 'AvgSp1400': [48.28, 37.25]}, geometry=geoms)
gdf.to_file('combined_data.shp')